# Kinetic energy of a solid

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, solid-mechanics

Considering an inertial reference frame with origin O, the first part expresses the angular momentum of a system as the sum of the angular momentum of the center of mass and the angular momentum applied to the particles relative to the center of mass. How can we demonstrate this theorem ?

$$\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{r}_{CoM}×\sum_{i}m_i \mathbf{v}_{CoM}+\mathbf{L}' =\mathbf{L}_{CoM}+ \mathbf{L}' $$

Comment: If you have the book An Introduction to Mechanics by Kleppner it’s in section 7.8 (pg-267). Tell me then I can I send a picture or explain the theorem in an answer.

Comment: actually , i don't have the book , do you ?

Comment: Isn't this just *Steiner's theorem*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem

Comment: No , actually , it's the first theorem of Koenig

Comment: @MohamedHarek Is equation $(2)$ in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Center_of_mass) section of the wikipedia article on angular momentum the same as the one you ask? The derivation is above the formula. Does this help?